# Simulink: How to get a buffer size that can be changed in C code?

Tags: c, size, buffer, signal-processing, simulink

I'm using a buffer from DSP System Toolbox in my Simulink model and genereate C code with Embedded Coder. I would like to have some kind of a parameter or define for the buffer size in my generated c code, so I can change it in the c code afterwars. Something like a "#define BUFFER_SIZE 100" or any other definition that can be changed directly in c code.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: sounds like you want a variable like `int BUFFER_SIZE = 100;`

Comment: Also a possibility. But for some reason I'm not able to specify this in the Simulink model, so that it comes out like this in the c code.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain _what_ went wrong when you tried the `int BUFFER_SIZE = 100` recommendation? Usually, if dealing with data types in Simulink is more difficult, I often simply cast the `double` into an `int` within the C code.

Comment: I try to get this definition out of auto code generation. And here is the problem: no matter how I define the buffer  size (by hard coded value or by a parameter) the size of the buffer is always hard coded in the c code. Therefore I have no definition like `int BUFFER_SIZE = 100` in the c code.